# while loop inside for loop is not showing all results but only 1

Tags: php, loops

i have these 2 codes that should do the same thing but the echo is completely different and i cant figure out why.
1rst code

```
<?php
    $runs = 10000;

    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $runs; $x++) {
        for($i=1;$i<1001;$i++) echo $i%15?$i%5?$i%3?$i:'koukou':'roukou':'koukouroukou'," ";
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    $elapsed = number_format($end - $start, 4);
    $one = number_format(($end - $start) / 500, 7);
    echo "$runs runs in $elapsed seconds, average of $one seconds per call";
?>
```

2nd code

```
<?php
    $runs = 10000;

    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $runs; $x++) {
        while(++$i<1001)echo$i%15?$i%5?$i%3?$i:'koukou':'roukou':'koukouroukou'," ";
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    $elapsed = number_format($end - $start, 4);
    $one = number_format(($end - $start) / 500, 7);
    echo "$runs runs in $elapsed seconds, average of $one seconds per call";
?>
```

why do i get different echo results ?

Comment: Has to do with whitespace? That's the only difference I see

Comment: `echo$i` -> `echo $i`

Comment: i is not initialized in the second case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for ($x = 0; $x < $runs; $x++) {
        while(++$i<1001)echo$i%15?$i%5?$i%3?$i:'koukou':'roukou':'koukouroukou'," ";
 }
```

should be

```
 for ($x = 0; $x < $runs; $x++) {
    $i=0;
        while(++$i<1001)echo$i%15?$i%5?$i%3?$i:'koukou':'roukou':'koukouroukou'," ";
 }
```